# track of meetings with ews is not correct processing

Tags: c#, ios, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I have next problem:
When I programmatically send meeting with ews, 
i insert id of calendar,email and another information in database
i track with Job on server every hour responses of the participants
with next code:

```
namespace TrackForMeeting
{
class TrackForMeeting
{
    //string ResponseType;
    //string IdItem;
    //string meetingInsert;
    static ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);



//        static string Tracking()
    {
        try
        {

            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("info@somemail.ru", "somepass");

            service.AutodiscoverUrl("info@somemail.ru", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

            var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone("UTC+3",
                TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset, "UTC+3", "UTC+3");

            string sql = "SELECT IdItem,StartDate,ResponseType,UpdStatus FROM dbo.RespForMeetings WHERE IsExpir = 0";

            string connectionString = @"Data Source=someserv;Initial Catalog=somedb;Integrated Security=True";

            string ResponseType;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

                connection.Open();
                // Создаем объект DataAdapter
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
                // Создаем объект DataTable
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                // Заполняем Datatable
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    Appointment meeting = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()));

                        ResponseType = meeting.RequiredAttendees[0].ResponseType.Value.ToString();

                        if (ResponseType != dt.Rows[i][2].ToString())
                        {
                            ExecCommand($"Update dbo.RespForMeetings SET ResponseType = '{ResponseType}',UpdStatus = 1 WHERE IdItem = '{dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()}'", connectionString);
                        }


                        if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()))
                        {
                            ExecCommand($"Update dbo.RespForMeetings SET IsExpir = 1 WHERE IdItem ='{dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()}'", connectionString);

                            meeting.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems, SendCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
                        }

                }
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e) { return e.Message; }

        return "";
    }

    public static bool RedirectionUrlValidationCallback(string redirectionUrl)
    {
        // The default for the validation callback is to reject the URL.
        bool result = false;

        Uri redirectionUri = new Uri(redirectionUrl);

        // Validate the contents of the redirection URL. In this simple validation
        // callback, the redirection URL is considered valid if it is using HTTPS
        // to encrypt the authentication credentials. 
        if (redirectionUri.Scheme == "https")
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }


    static string ExecCommand(string queryString, string conn)
    {

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            try
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return "";
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            { return ex.ToString(); }

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Tracking();

    }
```

when response income from person who have apple mobile device i have a trouble with this strings:

```
 ResponseType = meeting.RequiredAttendees[0].ResponseType.Value.ToString();

                        if (ResponseType != dt.Rows[i][2].ToString())
                        {
                            ExecCommand($"Update dbo.RespForMeetings SET ResponseType = '{ResponseType}',UpdStatus = 1 WHERE IdItem = '{dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()}'", connectionString);
                        }
```

and incoming response changing, but this script don't check this.Can anybody help?